# sql server back restore - login failed

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, production-environment

I have a local database on sql server 2008 R2 and working fine,

My hosting have sql server 2012 installed. After creating a fresh database on hosting server, I can connect easily to the blank database with given hosting credentials

I have created Sql Server 2008 backup and restored it to the hosting and every stops working.

```
Cannot open database "dbName" requested by the login. The login failed.
```

Before Creating a backup I did created a new user with the same credetianls as provided by hosting to connect their database.

There are few solutions suggesting to run the orphaned users query but am unable to connect to the database

http://sqlblog.com/blogs/eric_johnson/archive/2008/10/17/fixing-orphaned-users.aspx

Comment: You need sysadmin account (or help :)) to fix orphaned user and allow its access to restored database.

Answer (score 4):

Its created as the result of **orphan user** while doing backup and restore

First, make sure that this is the problem. This will lists the orphaned users:

> EXEC sp_change_users_login 'Report'

If you already have a login id and password for this user, fix it by doing:

> EXEC sp_change_users_login 'Auto_Fix', 'user'

If you want to create a new login id and password for this user, fix it by doing:

> EXEC sp_change_users_login 'Auto_Fix', 'user', 'login', 'password'

Another method worked for me

[image: a busy cat]
<sub>(source: [pinaldave.com](http://www.pinaldave.com/bimg/error4064_1.jpg))</sub>

[image: a busy cat]
<sub>(source: [pinaldave.com](http://www.pinaldave.com/bimg/error4064_2.jpg))</sub>

*Make sure to replace [test] with your username and master with yourdatabase name*

[image: a busy cat]
<sub>(source: [pinaldave.com](http://www.pinaldave.com/bimg/error4064_3.jpg))</sub>

Comment: I've been in this scenario probably a thousand times but this is the best fix I have ever run across. Cudos

Answer (score 0):

The account that you used to restore the database should have high enough privileges to also fix the login-user link. If that login gives you the above error, the default database of the login is most likely set to the one you just restored. In that case you can use the "options" button on the SSMS "Connect to Database Engine" dialog and select a different database in the "connect to database" field on the "Connection Properties" tab.

[image: Connect to Database Engine]

[image]

If you are using different tool that requires a connection string, you can explicitly specify the database in there too.

Once connected follow the advise in the article you linked to.

Comment: it isn't working. cannot connect to server but when I do try to connect using C# code, it says login failed. May be hosting blocked remote connectivity or something?